# Conditional Upload with Case

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

After doing a data migration from an old system, I came across a situation where there are records without dates.

[image: eg.1]

[image: eg.2]

The example I give above is the situation I have. I have nowhere to get the data from those NULL. So what is logically set to:

1. Get the Minor date within that range (00013 or 00021).
2. Update records with the earliest date of the series.

I suppose you make a CASE to achieve this. Someone can give me a help to figure out a way to get it?

Comment: Does this data have six columns or three columns?  What are the names of the columns?

Comment: Is the date column in the new table nullable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I set up a small POC to show you how to do this.

```
CREATE TABLE
    #T
(
    c1 char(9) NOT NULL
,   c2 datetime NULL
);

INSERT INTO
    #T
(
    c1
,   c2
)
VALUES
    ('0011.001', '2008-12-16T00:00:00.000')
,   ('0013.000', NULL)
,   ('0013.001', '2008-07-10T00:00:00.000')
,   ('0013.002', NULL)
,   ('9999.000', '2009-07-03T00:00:00.000');
```

At this point, we have a table with 3 unique "bands" which is what I'm calling the leading 4 character in that column. It's not a number as numbers don't have leading zeros. That's an artifact of presentation.

```
-- Identify the minimum value per first 4 digit values
SELECT
    LEFT(T.c1, 4) AS Band
,   MIN(T.c2) AS MinDate
FROM
    #T AS T
GROUP BY
    LEFT(T.c1, 4)
```

Running that query gives results as

```
Band    MinDate
0011    2008-12-16 00:00:00.000
0013    2008-07-10 00:00:00.000
9999    2009-07-03 00:00:00.000
```

That's what I expect. Now I simply need to use those values to backfill my missing dates.

```
-- Use this query to backfill data
-- the join condition here makes things painful for large data sets


UPDATE
    T
SET
    T.c2 = D.MinDate
FROM
    #T AS T
    -- use the above query as a derived table
    INNER JOIN
    (
        -- Identify the minimum value per first 4 digit values
        SELECT
            LEFT(T.c1, 4) AS Band
        ,   MIN(T.c2) AS MinDate
        FROM
            #T AS T
        GROUP BY
            LEFT(T.c1, 4)
    ) D
    ON D.Band = LEFT(T.c1, 4)
WHERE
    T.c2 IS NULL;
```

Of course, if you are using SQL Server 2005+ (which is likely these days), you could avoid using a join with the help of a window `MIN()`:

```
UPDATE
    T
SET
    T.c2 = T.MinDate
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            T.c2
        ,   MIN(T.c2) OVER (PARTITION BY LEFT(T.c1, 4)) AS MinDate
        FROM
            #T AS T
    ) T
WHERE
    T.c2 IS NULL;
```

Basically, the above works same as the previous solution except the `c2` values and their corresponding minimums are calculated and returned in the same subquery, which is used as a derived table (updatable in this context).

Answer (score 2):

First of all: It's good that you move this to a new database. It is a bad design to have range and sub-range in one column.

This should do:

```
update mytable
set mydate = 
(
  select min(mydate)
  from mytable other
  where left(other.range,5) = left(mytable.range,5)
)
where mydate is null;
```

Comment: @billinkc: No? This is standard SQL except for LEFT which is a T-SQL word. So what does it make invalid?

Comment: @billinkc: Okay, just checked it at sqlfiddle.com. SQL Server doesn't allow an alias for the updated table. Thanks, I'm correcting my answer accordingly.

Comment: You can use an alias for SQL Server, it just has to be in specified in the FROM clause

Answer (score 1):

Here's a query that should do what you want. It assumes that your source data table is named *YourData* and the relevant columns are named *Range* and *Date*.

If fixing this issue is a one time task, this query can be run from SSMS; if the fixing needs to be made a part of a recurring process, SSIS's *Execute SQL Task* can be used.

```
UPDATE YourData
SET Date = MinDate
FROM (
    -- get the minimum date inside a Band
    SELECT Band, MinDate = MIN(Date)
    FROM (
        -- split Range at the period, putting everything before the period into Band
        SELECT Band = LEFT(Range, CHARINDEX('.', Range, 0) - 1), 
            Date
        FROM YourData
    ) AS Data
    GROUP BY Band
) AS DateData
WHERE Date IS NULL
    AND DateData.Band = LEFT(Range, CHARINDEX('.', Range, 0) - 1)
```